# HiveServer2 hang on start

Tags: hadoop, hive

Im am new to hadoop/hive. Im trying to start Hive Server 2, but for some reason it seems to hang and never return to command prompt. Any ideas why this is happening?

```
$:/usr/local/hive$ hiveserver2
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hive-0.14.0/lib/hive-jdbc-0.14.0-standalone.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

It then stays like that forever. 
I also tried: `hive --service hiveserver2` but same result.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of the 2 SLF4J bindings being listed in the warning you'll need to exclude one of them from the classpath.

Even though this is a warning SLF4J will pick one logging framework/implementation and bind with it - binding is determined by the JVM and is mostly considered a random function.

then try this,

```
hive --service hiveserver2
```